# Should I be leery of using boost::archive?

Tags: c++, base64, boost-serialization

I want to use boost::archive::iterators::base64_from_binary.  But I can't seem to figure out why it is under "archive."  What does this imply?  Should I be leery of using this code for any reason?

Thanks--

Answer (score 6):

I *think* that the archive refers to it's function in archiving data, not as being obsolete...

Comment: I would have thought the very same, so +1.

Comment: Oh, haha. That would make sense--hope you're right. Adding to my leeryness is the fact that documentation is scant and lacking example code on boost.

Comment: Agreed, the documentation is a little sparse.

Answer (score 4):

`boost::archive` is a namespace used in the Serialization library. In general, it's ok to use stuff in boost as long as it's not in a namespace called `detail`.